# How to send a linked image by email

Tags: html, image, email, html-email

I would like to send a linked (not embedded) image by email.

[i.e: http://www.konbini.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/3/files/2018/03/a9a08770bba415c3b9a14cb162.jpg]

Do you know what kind of html code  have to write in the email?
I want to place the code within the body of the email.

I tried this but it's not working: 
`<img src="https://www.konbini.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/3/files/2018/03/a9a08770bba415c3b9a14cb162.jpg">`

I am using Outlook or Gmail also.

Thank you !

M

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3554/how-to-paste-raw-html-into-an-email-in-gmail

Comment: Thank you Ali! So yes it solves my problem's post. But my final goal is to send an email with R programming language using the mailR package. So I will create a new post to explain this.

Comment: You question is vague, missing information using R to send. Check your code to see which mime type your code is sending. Its supposed to send `text/html`, i have a feeling you are sending `text/plain`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the email is coded in HTML, you can use the following code:

```html
<a href="https://www.konbini.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/3/files/2018/03/a9a08770bba415c3b9a14cb162.jpg">https://www.konbini.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/3/files/2018/03/a9a08770bba415c3b9a14cb162.jpg</a>
```

In emails there's also a abbreviation. `<https://www.konbini.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/3/files/2018/03/a9a08770bba415c3b9a14cb162.jpg>`

You can enter these codes if the format is HTML.

Also, this is the exact same thing as insering an hyperlink to a webpage.

Comment: Hello D.Pardal, thank you for your help. Are you sure this code is working?: 
<a href="https://www.konbini.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/3/files/2018/03/a9a08770bba415c3b9a14cb162.jpg"> </a>   When I copy paste this in the body email I just receive this brut text. And I am in html mode.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood what I am looking for, the final output I would like in the email in the image, not just the link. I tried the code but it is not showing the image.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, @ML_Enthousiast. Do you want an image that, when clicked, opens itself (the image url) in the browser/email software?

Comment: Hi, so not exactly, my goal is to go from a written script (probably html) written in the body of the email, that will, when the email is received, display the image directly in the body of the email.

Comment: Then, the code you had in the question is the right one. Maybe your mail software/service just dosen't support raw HTML to be inserted the way you are trying to.

Comment: I am using gmail with Chrome navigation so really classic one. Does this work on your side?

Comment: Why don't you use that "insert image" button then? It dosen't support URLs?

Comment: it does. But my end goal is to send automated emails containing images with R programming language. I can send emails with R and the body can contain html script, so I am looking for the right script that will display the image within the body of the email.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help! I actually found the solution. In the parameters of the mailR package, I was using the following

`html=TRUE, inline=TRUE`

but it should be  `html=TRUE, inline=FALSE` if the image is from an url.